# CTKD implementation issue on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am working on an audio device project with dual-mode Bluetooth. I want to create a seamless connection experience with iOS devices, so I use CTKD with iOS. This gives us the ability to connect both BR/EDR and BLE without leaving our app in the system settings.
It works perfectly if the initial pairing happened inside the app. I got both BR/EDR and BLE connected and working and only one device shows on the Bluetooth page.
But if I pair the Bluetooth(BR/EDR) first in the system settings and then go to the app to pair BLE. The app initiated a new CTKD process, which creates a new BLE connection beside the BR/EDR connection.
My question is if I pair BR/EDR first in the Bluetooth settings, is there a way that I can only pair BLE and didn't trigger the CTKD while keeping the one device displayed on the Bluetooth settings page? Or anything else that can get the same result?